# How can I call a Javascript function multiple times from C# Code-Behind? It's only executing once

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a project at the moment, for which I will need to call JavaScript functions with multiple parameters from C# Code-Behind as the controls are being created dynamically(in code-behind).

I decided to open up a new project just to test a basic JavaScript and it's functionality with just one parameter to see if it would work but I was very unsuccessful even with that.

I have tried to read many other answers I found online, including here on stackoverflow ofcourse. Most just tell me that I have to give each textbox an ID or that I must change the "key" attribute in the `registerclientscriptblock` and `registerstartupscript` methods, both of which I have tried without any success. I guess there could be something wrong with my JavaScript function as well, which is not my forte(heard the word in a movie, love it, not the movie though). Please help me if you can and want to.

What I am doing is creating some textboxes, giving them ID's and passing the client IDs as the parameter in the JavaScript function, which is supposed to simply change their background colors and text colors.

What's happening is that only one of the textboxes(the last one inserted into the function) is showing changes made from the JavaScript, but of course I want all of them to be showing these changes.

Here is the Script:
[image: JavaScript]

The only reason I put added `window.onload` is because before this I was getting null exceptions. I'm sure there is a better, perhaps correct, way of doing this but I don't know it.

Here is the Code-Behind and the Result/Output of the program: [image: Code Behind]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you should include your script as script in the question not images :)

Comment: why inside function `call_me` you have `window.onload` when you are calling it through code behind . . . . and welcome to SO :)

Comment: Good Story.....Welcome to SO

Comment: I used window.onload because I was getting null exceptions without it, I wasn't sure what else to do.

Comment: you have to wrap `script_to_load` string variable with `script` blocks

Comment: My understanding was that the "true" condition in the RegisterClientScriptBlock function does this.

Comment: could you append each script in a string and then register

Comment: I will try that, but I would prefer to have the script written once and just call it with a different parameter each time because if I want to call it thirty times, it would just cost me load time recreating the same script 30 times and then calling it.

Comment: Also, thank you for the welcomes, and the Edit @AshleyMedway

Answer (score 0):

Here, Problem is you write "window.onload". You have to remove from your code.

You can do like this.

1) Put script in Head.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function call(id) {
             var field = document.getElementById(id);
             field.style.color = 'red';
             field.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

      }
    </script>
```

2) Create form in body.

```
 <form runat="server">
    <div id="text" runat="server"></div>
 </form>
```

3) Put c# code in Page_Load method.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      TextBox tb = new TextBox();
      tb.ID = "textbox" + i;
      tb.Text = "Textbox"+i;
      panel.Controls.Add(tb);
      text.Controls.Add(panel);
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "textbox" + i, "<script>call('textbox" + i + "');</script>", false);
  }
```

Is this Clear? If you have any question. Let me know.

Comment: Hi, after trying this, I am getting a null exception. "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference".

Comment: Please check id of created textbox developer tool of Browser.